# How to sort FTPFile[] array object based on timestamp in java

Tags: java, ftp, comparator

I am polling files from FTP server. I have an use case to sort the array FTPFile[] based on timestamp. I want to first modified file as first object and last modified file as last object in my FTPFile[] array object.

Can some one please suggest me how to do in java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Java7** *or lower*:
See [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge)'s Post


**Java8** :

```
final FTPFile[]           files  = new FTPFile[100];   //or what ever    
final Comparator<FTPFile> sorter = (e1, e2) -> e1.getTimestamp().compareTo(e2.getTimestamp());

Arrays.sort(files, sorter);
```

Comment: The result is a `Stream` though, not an array

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom `Comparator` for `FTPFile` objects, and then use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T%3aA-java.util.Comparator-) using that `Comparator`.

Note that this method sorts arrays *in place*.

Assuming you are talking about Apache's commons-net FTPFile, the comparator can be written as such:

```
private static final Comparator<FTPFile> CMP = new Comparator<>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final FTPFile a, final FTPFile b)
    {
        return a.getTimeStamp().compareTo(b.getTimeStamp());
    }
}
```

---

If you use Java 8 then look at @ifLoop's solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming FTPFile is a kind of java File, or may be translated to get one

Collections.sort(list, comparator), where you may use the following comparator:

```
class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

@Override
public int compare(File o1, File o2) {

    try {
        BasicFileAttributes attr1 = Files.readAttributes(o1.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
        BasicFileAttributes attr2 = Files.readAttributes(o2.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
        return attr1.lastModifiedTime().compareTo(attr2.lastModifiedTime());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle this the way you want
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: VERY bad idea to handle IOException this way!

Comment: That is up to the developer to handle the exception, this is sample only :)

Comment: Still, you are basically botching a `Comparator` because of poor exception handling

Comment: Like I said, it is a sample. That is not how it is meant to be in the actual code. The person developing would know what they want to do with the exception. Log it an move on, or stop the comparison.